# Dividing HTML page into horizontal sections, without vertical scrollbars

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6FUQ/

HTML is:

```
<div id="container">
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <section class="half"></section>
        <section class="half"></section>
    </main>
</div>
```

And CSS is:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
main {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
.half {
    height: 50%;
}
.half:first-child {
    background: blue;
}
.half:last-child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

In it, I have a thin ribbon at the top, and I want to divide the rest of the screen into two equal sections, but I don't want vertical scrollbar to appear.

I tried `margin-bottom: 50px;` for `main`, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Height of "main" should be 100% - 50px. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6FUQ/1/).

```
main{height: calc(100% - 50px);}
```

Comment: this solved my problem but "The following features are at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period: ‘calc()’, ‘toggle()’, ‘attr()’." CSS Values and Units Module Level 3 - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

Comment: true, I suggest you should keep header also in % basis. for example 20% header, 80% rest of the body.

Answer (score 4):

To make it work on old browsers, you could use absolute positioning.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6FUQ/4/)

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are already using % to set height... Why don't you use it again to solve your problem?

```
header {
    height: 10%;
    background: gray;
    max-height:50px; //this will ensure your header will never go bigger than 50px
}
main {
    height: 90%;
    background: green;
}
```

PS: The only time your header is going to be smaller than 50px is when the browser is smaller than 500px (which will be only in some landscape mobile devices)

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S6FUQ/3/)**